# Compiling Audacity with VisualStudio 2015 and C++ produces multiple C1189 & C4005 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visualstudio 2015. On Windows 10.I am trying to specifically use the latest VS and SDKs, I do not want to back track to VS2013.
I have gone through the entire code base of Audacity, and changed the instances of

```
#define snprintf _snprintf
```

to

```
#if _MSC_VER < 1900
   #define snprintf _snprintf
#endif
```

However, on rebuilding - I'm still getting these errors.

```
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1925): warning C4005: 'snprintf': macro redefinition
22>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1925): note: command-line arguments:  see previous definition of 'snprintf'
22>C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\stdio.h(1927): fatal error C1189: #error:  Macro definition of snprintf conflicts with Standard Library function declaration
```

I can not see how to get around this? Where is it colliding and thus producing the fatal error.
There are 24 Solutions in the build, and all but three of them build. Theo nes that don't build so far are:
libnyquist
libsndfile
lv2

Comment: "note: command-line arguments".  So not a #define in the source code, a /D command line argument.  Hard to guess, I don't see it in the .vcxproj files on github.  Crap like this does make it complete rocket science to ever get a C++ library built.